# Dual boot legacy Windows and UEFI Fedora

Tags: boot, multi-boot, uefi

I have a UEFI PC with two hard drives. On C: I have my main OS - Windows 10, which I have installed in legacy mode (or at least BIOS sees it as non-UEFI). On D: I installed Fedora 24 in UEFI mode (accidentally). Both /boot and /uefi/boot Fedora partitions reside on disk D. I can boot either OS, but only through BIOS.

I'm tired of going to BIOS settings every time I want to boot my secondary OS. I want to be greeted with grub or w/e bootloader which will let me boot any OS with just a couple of gestures.

I tried EasyBCD but it didn't work. I do get a bootloader menu, but Fedora option (UEFI one) doesn't work. Instead of booting OS it just boots up some GRUB4DOS command line. Is there any way to fix my problem other than reinstalling Fedora?

Comment: You can't boot Windows in legacy mode and Fedora in UEFI mode, UEFI and legacy Mode, conflicts with Windows they can't co-exist

Comment: @Ramhound could you possibly provide some sources for the OP to research from?

Comment: @Burgi My statement is based on years of experience I have no sources to provide

Comment: <citation needed> . Quite frankly, in situations like this, it might be a good idea to treat statements like this as you would an answer. If you're going to say something that seems authoritative, it really should be backed up. Comments shouldn't be a space for half-cooked answers in potentia.

Comment: Agreed, especially when said user repeatedly complains about others not providing sources.